# What to use in place of stepwise/best subset selection based on AIC/BIC?

Tags: predictive-models, feature-selection, model-selection

I have read numerous articles and posts about why stepwise model selection/best subset model selection is a horrible idea. Interestingly, few of them provide practical advice besides "data dredging is bad".

My question is, suppose I only care about how accurate my model will predict (to be more extreme, I am willing to predict number of people bitten by shark using sales of ice-creams), what are common ways to perform model selection if I want to use linear model and its variations?

Comment: Stepwise/best subset selection *are common* ways. You are probably more interested in *good* ways. Instead of selection, try regularization. And generally try cross validation rather than using the entire sample for model fitting because in the latter case it is difficult to avoid overfiting and data dredging.

Comment: @RichardHardy I usually use model selection with cross validation :) Yes, I am interested in _good_ ways. I just want to restrict the discussion in a narrow situation. Every method has its problem and I'm more interested in when _can_ you use a certain method

Answer (score 2):

Use lasso

Although, if you just care about accuracy, then why are excluding methods which do not perform variable selection? Variable selection is *usually* only performed when interpretability is important. Yes, people do also use it to increase accuracy, but only when they can reasonably assume that only a subset of variables (usually much smaller than the entire set of variables) will be predictive.

Try ridge regression as well. It may outperform lasso, but you wont get variable selection.